# Line of Sight between sets of two points each

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, point, elevation

So I have a list of points with their longitude and latitude (Lon_A, Lat_A and Lon_B, Lat_B). I also have a DEM layer from the SRTM for the relevant location. I need to check if line of sight exists between these point pairs. What I'm essentially doing is checking if it's possible to create a microwave link between given point pairs.

So in a nutshell If I have a data set of point pairs I need to get a Boolean output whether Line of Sight exists or not. Wondering if there's a way to do this using QGIS or GRASS GIS. Looking for a process where this can be done en masse instead of checking each individual point pair.

Comment: You could perform a viewshed https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/ and https://www.giscourse.com/how-to-create-a-visibility-analysis-with-qgis/ using SRTM elevation to see if each point can 'see' any of the others.. beware though SRTM is not very accurate for elevations, before moving onto your next phase acquire better elevation data for your viewsheds or risk a massive failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tutorial using the QGIS `Visibility analysis plugin`, followed by some SQL querying for establishing intervisibility networks: https://landscapearchaeology.org/2019/intervisibility-qgis/ This seems like one of the more straightforward ways to achieve your goal.

Another option might be to use `r.viewshed` from GRASS GIS, available in the QGIS processing toolbox ([manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html)). However, as the output from `r.viewshed` is visibility rasters associated with individual points, automating detection of intervisibility between a larger number of points would be a somewhat more involved process that might be best solved through some scripting.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you very much,

Comment: In addition, there is a multi-viewshed GRASS GIS addon available: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.viewshed.cva.html